# What does SpatialDropout1D() do to output of Embedding() in Keras?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, lstm, dropout

Keras model looks like this

```
inp = Input(shape=(maxlen, ))
x = Embedding(max_features, embed_size, weights=[embedding_matrix], trainable=False)(inp)
x = SpatialDropout1D(dropout)(x)
x = Bidirectional(LSTM(num_filters, return_sequences=True))(x)
max_pool = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(x)
x = concatenate([x_h, max_pool])
outp = Dense(6, activation="sigmoid")(x)
```

According to the [documentation](https://keras.io/layers/core/#spatialdropout1d) the output shape = input shape i.e. (samples, timesteps, channels)

**Questions**

1. What does SpatialDropout1D() really do to the output of Embedding()? I know the output of LSTM Embedding is of dimension (batch_size, steps, features).
2. Does SpatialDropout1D() just randomly replace some values of word embedding of each word by 0?
3. How is SpatialDropout1D() different from Dropout() in Keras?

Comment: Intuitively This version performs the same function as Dropout, however it drops entire 1D feature maps instead of individual elements..

Comment: What is a 1D feature maps in the context of Embedding()?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50393666/how-to-understand-spatialdropout1d-and-when-to-use-it

Comment: Dropping the cols itself! Is what I can conclude.. need to play around them like visualisation of the embedding to confirm it!

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it removes all the pixel in a row from **all** channels. 
eg: take `[[1,1,1], [2,4,5]]`, there are 3 points with values in 2 channels, by doing SpatialDropout1D it zeros an entire row ie all attributes of a point is set to 0; like `[[1,1,0], [2,4,0]]`

number of such choices would be `3C0 + 3C1+ 3C2 + 3C3 = 8`

The intuition behind this is in many cases for an image the adjacent pixels are correlated, so hiding one of them is not helping much, rather hiding entire row, that's gotta make a difference. [reference material](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/282282/how-is-spatial-dropout-in-2d-implemented)